# Construct LineString using org.geolatte.geom

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-spatial

How do I convert the following MySQL expression to a corresponding `org.geolatte.geom.LineString`, using the `org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial` library.

```
LineString(Point(-1, start_timestamp), Point(1, end_timestamp));
```

The `DSL.linestring` requires a `org.geolatte.geom.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem`, but I'm unsure which one I should use for this particular case.

What I have tried with so far

```
C2D position1 = new C2D(-1, 1546301554.000000);
C2D position2 = new C2D(1, 1546301559.000000);

GeographicCoordinateReferenceSystem gcrs = CoordinateReferenceSystems.mkGeographic(UNKNOWN_Angular);

LineString<C2D> lineString = DSL.linestring(gcrs, position1, position2);
```

The goal is to find overlapping dates, using `LineString`. I got it working using only SQL, but I'm a bit unsure how to implement the `LineString` using geolatte, primarily which CoordinateReferenceSystem I should be using. The `LineString` will be stored as a `Geometry` field, in a database table.

The `LineString` will include two `Point`, where the y coordinates will correspond to the start_datetime and the end_datetime.

Update:
Maybe this approach is preferable

```
C2D position1 = new C2D(-1, 1546301554 (EPOCH START TIMESTAMP));
C2D position2 = new C2D(1, 1546301559 (EPOCH END TIMESTAMP));

ProjectedCoordinateReferenceSystem test = CoordinateReferenceSystems.mkProjected(UNKNOWN_LINEAR);

LineString<C2D> lineString = DSL.linestring(test, position1, position2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually using the `geolatte-geom` library here, not `hibernate-spatial` (although the latter does include the former as a dependency).  Your code doesn't work because you're mixing two approaches (direct and via the DSL), and you're mixing cartesian and geographic coordinates. Also, for angular (geographic) coordinates, the allowed range is [-180, 180] for longitude, and [-90,+90] for latitude. So I'm not sure in what coordinate system you're working.

The best approach would be:

```
import static org.geolatte.geom.builder.Dsl.*
GeographicCoordinateReferenceSystem gcrs = CoordinateReferenceSystems.mkGeographic(UNKNOWN_Angular);

Linestring<G2D> ls = linestring(gcrs, g(-1, 50.4), g(1, 50.4));
```

Have a look at the [README](https://github.com/geolatte/geolatte-geom) that gives an introduction into the library.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to find overlapping dates using LineString, I've got it working using sql, but I'm a bit unsure how to implement it using geolatte and hibernate-spatial. 

What I'm trying to achieve;
1. Construct a LineString with datetime start and datetime end
2. Put it into a LineString column, using hibernate.

My example above works, and the linestring is stored correctly into the database column (LINESTRING(-1 1593558000,1 1593561300)), but as you have noticed, I'm a bit unsure which CoordinateReferenceSystems I should be using, for this case.

Comment: I think you should use one with a cartesian coordinate system. `CoordinateReferenceSystems.UNKNOWN_PROJECTED_METER` should do.